# Customize MS Word Ribbon and Tabs in Winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms, office-interop, ribbon-control, winforms-interop

I have a MS Word 2013 document loaded in WinForm using C#. Are there any solution for the following:-

1)  Customize the Ribbon using Microsoft.Office.Interop

2)  Remove/disable the Quick access toolbar and File tab

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you can't use interop file to customize the Ribbon UI. If develop an add-in you have to implement the IRibbonExtensibility interface or embedd a custom markup into the Word file.
2. You can read more about the Ribbon UI and possible QAT customizations in the following series of articles in MSDN:

   - [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
   - [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
   - [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

The File tab belongs to the Bakcstage UI, you can read more about that in the [Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691833%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [Customizing the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee815851(v=office.14).aspx) articles in MSDN.